# Select2 error on tag when value is not the same as display value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Let say I have this select box:

```
<select id="example" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option selected value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

For communicating with many other parts of the site, the value cannot be changed. This is just for demo example, the actual use case is something more complicated and the display value need to be different with the actual form value that is going to be submitted.

To allow autocomplete and adding new tag, select2 is used.

```
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month',
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
});
```

[JS fiddle for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rLmztr2d/237/)

The problem is that when typing the full month name, like "January", and then press space, instead of selecting the existing "January" option (which is what I expected), it just creates a new tag with value `January`.

After some repeated testing, I found that this just happens when the actual value is not the same as the display value. Is there a way I can keep the two values different but make it select the already exist option?

Comment: i think you need some one type `January` and `  January` you want only `January` to get selected. So you can filter result which is there in option and neglect unwanted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilise the `createTag` event by searching for a match.

If there's no match, and since you don't want to add a new tag, simply return `null`:

```
var options = $('#example option');

$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month',
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
  createTag: function(params) {    
    var matchedVal = options.filter(function () { return $(this).html() === params.term; }).val();    
    return (matchedVal) ? { id: matchedVal, text: params.term } : null
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2yu87gyf/

**EDIT:**

Per your comment that you want to create the tag if it doesn't already exist - use this `return` statement instead:

```
return (matchedVal) ? { id: matchedVal, text: params.term } : { id: params.term, text: params.term }
```

Create unmatched tag demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2yu87gyf/1/

Comment: I do want to create tag when there is no match. I just don't want to add a tag when there is a match. Mind editing your answer? I think you are close to the bounty. (i.e. what should I return if I want to add a tag?)

Comment: Marked as correct answer. For awarding bounty, stackoverflow locked the function. Need to wait for 9 more hours before unlocking.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

*remove **tags** option as it will create new tags on the fly*

```
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month',
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
});
```

Comment: @cytsunny  accept answer if it worked for u.Thank you

Comment: I need it to create tags on the fly. I just don't want it to create when the tag already exist at the beginning.

Comment: Worst still, even if I don't need the tag function, pressing space button still cannot select the existing option.